# How to append &nbsp inside the last <p> tag with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to append `&nbsp;` to the end of the last tag with jQuery?
For example, my html would be something like this:

```
<div>
    <p>line1</p>
    <p>line2</p>  
</div>
```

I want the end result to be:

```
<div>
    <p>line1</p>
    <p>line2 &nbsp;</p>  
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to consider just using the :last-child class (not available in ie6, ie7, ie8, available in ie9 and good browsers) and just adding some slight right-margin instead of adding content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

`$("div p:last").append("&nbsp;");`

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/d8AGr/